# django form: error message with aware datetime

Tags: django, validation, datetime, django-forms, django-timezone

I'm trying to get add a datetime to my form error message. Unfortunately it is rendered in UTC (my TIME_ZONE), but should be in the current timezone.

```
def clean(self):
    # print(get_current_timezone()) > Europe/Berlin
    cleaned_data = super(LegForm, self).clean()
    departure_scheduled = cleaned_data.get('departure_scheduled')
    # check departure in journey
    if departure_scheduled < self.instance.journey.start:
        journey_start = localize(self.instance.journey.start)
        # print(self.instance.journey.start.tzinfo) > UTC
        self.add_error(
            'departure_scheduled',
            _('Error Message (%(start)s).') % {'start': journey_start}
        )
```

`print(get_current_timezone())` returns `Europe/Berlin`

`print(self.instance.journey.start.tzinfo)` returns `UTC`

The current timezone is activated. Is there any equal to `localize()` to convert the datetime object to the current timezone?

Comment: Use [`localtime()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/utils/#django.utils.timezone.localtime).

Comment: That's what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I could use:

```
journey_start = localize(self.instance.journey.start.astimezone(get_current_timezone()))
```

But it feels like fighting against django's timezone support.

**UPDATE**:

Thank's to Kevin Christopher Henry comment, here's the django tool I was looking for:

```
from django.utils import timezone
journey_start = timezone.localtime(self.instance.journey.start)
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/timezones/#usage